# Eliminating space at the end of list environments

Tags: lists, framed

I am attempting to eliminate the vertical space at the end of listing environments (`enumerate`, `itemize` and `describe`) but only when the list environment is at the end of a `leftbar` environment from the `framed` package. This particular circumstance produces an awkward overhang of the leftbar (working example below). So far I've considered three options:

1. I realize I can adjust `\topsep`, `\itemsep`, and `\partopsep`, but this would not condition on being at the end of a `leftbar` environmnet, and affect the whole document.
2. I could redefine the list environments to include some negative space at the end. However, this would not condition on being at the end of a `leftbar` environment.
3. Finally, I could implement both the above solutions manually on a case-by-case basis. This seems inelegant and makes for a lot of work in longer documents.

If anyone has a solution it would be very much appreciated!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed}


\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

\item Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

\end{enumerate}
\end{leftbar}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine the `leftbar` environment to `\unskip` the last skip inserted by the `itemize`-like environments.

Add the following lines in your preamble:

```
\let\oldendleftbar\endleftbar
\renewcommand{\endleftbar}{\unskip\oldendleftbar}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{framed,lipsum}

\let\oldendleftbar\endleftbar
\renewcommand{\endleftbar}{\unskip\oldendleftbar}


\begin{document}

\begin{leftbar}
\begin{itemize}

\item Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

\item Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

\item Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.

\end{enumerate}
\end{leftbar}

\begin{leftbar}
\lipsum[1]
\end{leftbar}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user126350 You're welcome. Happy it helped.